# Get table name of the program for Store Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

You can get table name from the program.

Like the following code:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[sp_SelectAll]
@BankName nvarchar(50)

As
Begin
    Select *
    From @BankName
End
```

This is the error code.

There is another way?

Comment: It's generally poor form to use `select *` in production code (except within `EXISTS` tests). There's another bad vibe about this code though - either you're writing a stored procedure which can return wildly different types of result sets, or you've got multiple tables with identical structures. Either of these is usually a sign of a poor design.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it like:

exec('select * from ' + @BankName)

but its not good practice to use this..

You can learn more about dynamic sql from :

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1160

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-dynamic-sql-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Tables cannot be parametrized. You have to write dynamic sql i.e generate sql strings and execute it using exec.

exec ('select * from ' + @BankName)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  Create Procedure [dbo].[sp_SelectAll]
        @BankName nvarchar(50)

        As
        Begin
            EXEC('Select * from '+ @BankName)
        End
```

You need to work with using `dynamic SQL` to make that work properly.